# screen.width return wrong size javascript android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am writing 1 app use phonegap.

I use **screen.width** and **.height** to get screen width and height.

But when i test, is return wrong value. This is some device and simulator i tested:

`Samsung galaxy mini 2.3.4 (240x320): return random in (240x301) and (320x401)`

`Panasonic 102p 2.3.5 (540x960): return random in (0x0) and (320x622) and (540x922)`

work perfect in simulator mobile and table run android 4.0.1

`HTC ONE X android 4.1.1 (720x1280): work perfect`

After some test, i think it wrong because android 2.

I tried:

`screen.width (height)`

`screen.availWidth (height)`

`window.innerWidth (height)`

`$(window).width() (height)`

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />`

Comment: Have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334221/screen-width-and-screen-height-different-values-in-different-apis-devices

Answer (score 1):

I use the next code and works well.

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```